# Hilbert series of the polynomial ring $K[X_1, \dots, X_s]$

Tags: combinatorics, commutative-algebra

> Let $K$ be a field and $a_1, \dots, a_s \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}$. How can I compute the Hilbert series for $K[X_1, \dots, X_s]$, where $\deg(X_i)=a_i$?

Comment: I've added to combinatorics tag, since this is essentially asking for the number of partitions of (an arbitrary exponent) $n$ into multiples of the given $a_i$'s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try induction on the number of variables. For the $n-1 \Rightarrow n$ step use the following equality:

$$P(K[X_1, \dots, X_n], t) = P(K[X_1, \dots, X_{n-1}], t) \cdot \frac{1}{1-t^{a_n}}$$

where $P(M,t)$ is the Hilbert series of the $R$-module $M$.

You can obtain it remembering the Hilbert function is additive and considering the exact sequence $$0 \rightarrow K[X_1, \dots, X_n]_d\stackrel{\cdot X_n}\rightarrow K[X_1, \dots, X_n]_{d+a_n}\rightarrow K[X_1, \dots, X_{n-1}]_{d+a_n}\rightarrow 0. $$

Answer (score 2):

The Hilbert series you ask for is the product for $i=1,\ldots,s$ of the Hilbert series for $K[X]$ with $\deg(X)=a_i$. That Hilbert series if $\frac1{1-X^{a_i}}$ so your answer is
$$
  \frac1{\prod_{i=1}^s(1-X^{a_i})}.
$$
When many of the $a_i$ are equal, you can simplify this using the (binomial) series for $(1-X)^{-k}$.

Comment: It is true  only if $X_i$ are algebraically  independed

Comment: @Leox: In $K[X_1,\ldots,X_s]$ the $X_i$ _are_ algebraically independent over$~K$. If the $X_i$ were algebraically dependent, how would it be possible to assign degrees independently to them?